# SDWebImage or FFImageLoading Authentication for Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios, sdwebimage, ffimageloading

I need to load images that required basic authentication.  I am using SDWebImage.  I have a directory that is open to the public and those images load correctly.  When I try and load images from a directory that requires authentication, it never loads the image.  Is it possible to pass a username and password for authentication?  I have added the following code, but it doesn't appear to help:

```
SDWebImageManager.SharedManager.ImageDownloader.Username = "myusername";
SDWebImageManager.SharedManager.ImageDownloader.Password = "mypassword";

ivPic.SetImage(
    url: new NSUrl("https://www.example.com/secure/pic.jpg"),
    placeholder: UIImage.FromBundle("NotAvailable.jpg")
);
```

EDIT:
I have now become desperate as I cannot seem to access the images in an authentication required folder no matter what.  I found a link using a different package (FFImageLoading) that gives an example [here](https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/173), but I am not using a token only a username and password via Basic Authentication.  How can I get what the '_authService.GetToken' is?

```
ImageService.Initialize(new Configuration { HttpClient = new HttpClient(new AuthenticatedHttpImageClientHandler(_authService.GetToken)) });
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I could never access pictures in a different folder than the web service itself.  Setting the username and password as mentioned above works (and is required, which I am not sure why) when the folder is inside of the web service I am authenticating through.